# Set MTU in Win XP from the command line

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, settings, network-interface, mtu

I want to set MTU from the command line. I'm running under XP.

I've tried:

netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1300 store=persistent

But it's not working.

I've tried to change "ipv4" to "ip" but it didn't help. The token "subinterface" is not recognized.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comprehensive answer at SuperUser: [How to tell what MTU is being used in Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/37686/how-to-tell-what-mtu-is-being-used-in-windows-xp)

Comment: So no option for setting in XP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the MTU in Windows XP via command line in this format:

netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1300 store=persistent

As per http://my.bergersoft.net/2010/05/13/how-to-change-mtu-size-on-windows-xpvista72008/